# Cancel Keypress in VB .Net not working

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to capture the keydown event in a rich text box in VB .Net.

According to the documentation and examples I have seen I just need to use e.Handled = True but this isn't working, I still get the key value placed in the rich text box.

My code is

```
    Private Sub Tagging_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles rtxReference.KeyDown
    If ((e.KeyCode = Keys.Z) AndAlso e.Control) Then
        'MsgBox("Undo")
        rtxReference.Text = sPrevious
    Else
        If cbxHotKeyTags.Checked Then
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.T Then
                sTagName = "article-title"
            ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then
                sTagName = "volume"
            ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F Then
                sTagName = "fpage"
            ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.L Then
                sTagName = "lpage"
            ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.I Then
                sTagName = "issuee"
            End If
            e.Handled = True
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If I add e.SuppressKeyPress = True, then the character is not placed in the text box!

Comment: I don't think that you read that documentation properly. It states that setting `e.Handled` to `True` in the event handler for the form means that child controls won't raise the event. Are you doing that? No, you're not. To prevent a character being entered using `e.Handled`, you'd have to set the form's `KeyPreview` property to `True` and then set `e.Handled` to `True` in the `KeyPress` event handler of the form.